# How to exclude a class from selection using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have this HTML element structure.

```
    <div class="parent">
       <div class="myChild">A</div>
       <div class="myChild">B</div>
   </div>

   <div class="parent">
       <div class="myChild notYou">C</div>
       <div class="myChild">D</div>
   </div>
```

How do get all class `myChild` inside class `parent` but exclude the one with the class `notYou` from my selection? I use this script:

```
$(".parent").not(".parent + .notYou").each(function(i){
//something
});
```

But, the class `notYou` is still included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want all `.mychild` classes except `.notYou`.

Here is how you could get that:

```js
$(".parent > .myChild:not(.notYou)").each(function(i){
   console.log($(this).html())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
       <div class="myChild">A</div>
       <div class="myChild">B</div>
   </div>

   <div class="parent">
       <div class="myChild notYou">C</div>
       <div class="myChild">D</div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the `not` method correctly. You can select the elements for this scenario either using the `not` method or the `:not` selector.

> $('.parent .myChild:not(.notYou)');  // :not selector

or

> $('.parent .myChild').not('.notYou'); // .not method

```js
$(".parent .myChild").not(".notYou").each(function(i){
   console.log($(this).html())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
       <div class="myChild">A</div>
       <div class="myChild">B</div>
   </div>

   <div class="parent">
       <div class="myChild notYou">C</div>
       <div class="myChild">D</div>
   </div>
```